# django and ajax returned data

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm trying to implement a quite easy ajax call but since its my first one, something goes wrong and I can't find why. After a users choice from a dropdown list I want another field of the form to be completed after the corresponding query. Here is my code:
jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#id_veh_id1').bind('click', function () {
            var val1 =$("#id_veh_id1").val();
            $.get(""+val1+"/", function(data) {
                result=data.veh_length;
                document.getElementById('id_vlength').value=result;
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

with url: `url(r'^(?P<user_id>\d+)/main_Webrequests/(?P<veh_id>\d+)/$', 'auth.views.test', name='test')`

and view:

```
def test(request, veh_id, user_id):   
    message = {"veh_length": ""}
    if request.is_ajax():
        vehicle1 = Vehicles.objects.get(id = veh_id)
        veh_length = vehicle1.vlength
        message['veh_length'] = vehicle1.vlength
    else:
        message = "yoohoo"
        json = simplejson.dumps(message)
    return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json')
```

When I try it with `veh_id` instead of `veh_length` everything seems to work fine but maybe I didn't understand sth well with the whole thing.

Comment: Can you check the response of the Ajax view? (For example go to the network tab in Chrome's Inspector while doing the request)

Comment: Yes,with veh_length I get Http 500 error.

Comment: You can also view your stacktrace there in the response tab if you have `DEBUG = True` which should point you the the Line with the Error!

Comment: wow I din't know that, it says "Exception Value: Decimal('3') is not JSON serializable". What am I supposed to do with that then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simplejson cannot dump a `Decimal` to JSON, you should be able to workaround that with something like:

```
message['veh_length'] = "%d" % vehicle1.vlength
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to serialize your json data in django code.....check this link for further reference..

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/